# Searching for duplicate values within sets of 'n' rows within a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTswXxlMFGFOYiG8jatnLTpN4hS3rhVouBfshRIMXTKi3wmpQuZ6MIabfjcqTXwqlILRcxOxr4o3xqc/pubhtml?gid=1249461985&single=true

I have the above spreadsheet set up to act as a daily schedule, in the range C5:I58. I have times in rows starting at 0800 and increasing in 30 min intervals e.g. 0830, 0900... until 1630 and then dates from today to today+6 as columns. Each time covers 3 rows and a value (retrieved via formula) can appear multiple times per day (i.e. per column) but in a maximum of 2 consecutive time periods i.e. twice within 6 consecutive rows.

What I would like to to is highlight the cells where the same value appears consecutively in the above case. I am aware that `=COUNTIF(C5:C58,C5)>1` can be used to find duplicate values in a column but don't think it can be adapted to this situation specifically.

Therefor I expect I might have to create an iteration loop, but I wouldn't know where to start in this case! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: rather than as a published sheet can you share the sample sheet via link so that we can see the formulas etc?

Comment: I would be glad to help, but it eludes me what you're trying to get. Can you fill a column of the table with a little bit more real data? There should be not colored texts as well, shouldn't? How would it look?

Comment: it seems you have a slot booking system, where items can be booked out in each 1/2 hour time slot, but can not be booked out twice (consecutively) within less than 1 hour. so an item can be booked out at 8:00, then again at 9:00, but not at 8:30. and the system allows for up to 3 items to be booked out in each half hour slot. does that sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on:
"Each time covers 3 rows and a value (retrieved via formula) can appear multiple times per day (i.e. per column)"

With condition:
in "a maximum of 2 consecutive time periods i.e. twice within 6 consecutive rows" and to "highlight the cells where the same value appears consecutively in the above case"

Applying Conditional Formatting to the range `C5:I58`

Where the **Format rule** selection is `Custom formula is`, and uses the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS((QUOTIENT(ROW()-5,3)*3)+2,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS((QUOTIENT(ROW()-5,3)*3)+10,COLUMN())),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))>1
```

It will highlight the individual cells (not the block of 3 cells) where there is a duplicate within `2 consecutive time periods`

Explanation:

`COUNTIF(.....)>1`
is when there are more than 1 (ie. a duplicate)

`INDIRECT(.....)`
allows us to use the ADDRESS as a range of values

`ADDRESS((QUOTIENT(ROW()-5,3)*3)+2,COLUMN())`
is the first cell of the range (in conditional formatting) to be counted

`ADDRESS((QUOTIENT(ROW()-5,3)*3)+10,COLUMN())`
is the last cell of the range (in conditional formatting) to be counted

`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))`
is the cell being compared

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

#### Highlight consecutive duplicates in column C

```
function consecdupes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e, i, a) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      if (e == a[i - 1]) {
        sh.getRange(i + 1, 3,2).setBackgrounds([["#ffff00"],["#ffff00"]]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It could be just one line in the loop: `sh.getRange(i+4,3,2,1).setBackground("#ffff00");`